# Say "See you tomorrow" in email for an phone interview

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, email

I was writting an email to decide the time for a quick phone interview with a recruiter, and say, it is decided to be 3pm this Friday. I hesitate about whether I can write "See you this Friday" at the end of the email, since we won't "see" each other this Friday. Is it okay to say that, or are there other proper expressions?

PS, the recruiter is almost of the same age as me and our emails start with "Hello + first name", so the whole conversation is really formal.

Answer (score 4):

To say "See you" you are implying you will be seeing them, in this case it would make more sense to sign off with something like "Speak to you this Friday".

Comment: Thank you for the reply!